# Answering questions that already have a good answer

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

I like to answer questions on SO as a form of learning, to reinforce, challenge, and refine my current understanding, as well as helping the asker of the question. Plus getting upvotes gives me a endorphin hit.

However, I've found that for many questions, somebody (usually with very high rep - 5 or 6 digits and depending on the tags usually one of a small number of people) will post a very good and complete answer to most questions within a few minutes.

This removes my motivation to answer the question, and to check for new questions, because there is already a sufficient answer and nothing to add, and I cannot spend so much time on this site to match such a response rate. If I did answer the question, it would contain duplicate information to an existing answer. In some cases where I've added information that wasn't in an existing answer, other answerers have incorporated that information into their answer and received further upvotes - this also de-motivates me.

As ivarni pointed out in the comments, it's possible to specifically search for unanswered questions. In many cases for older questions, it turns out the answer is actually in the comments - or the comments conclude that the question is not currently answerable.

What is the etiquette for posting answers to questions when you feel that either the question is already answered sufficiently, or that your answer will contain similar or the same information to an existing answer? What about if the answer is in a comment, not a proper answer? And what is the etiquette regarding editing an answer to include information from other answers?

Comment: If you go to the "unanswered" tab in the question list you'll usually find plenty of older questions with no answers and you'll most likely have no competition when answering those.

Comment: *And what is the etiquette regarding editing an answer to include information from other answers?* I think there's a duplicate to this question on Meta. IIRC, the answer to this one is also "don't". We don't want multiple distinct answers in one answer post.

Comment: Related Question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: Is moving to a timezone other than the ones the high-rep users live in an option?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I live in Japan, I'm guessing that's not a common SO user timezone. ;-)

Comment: @ivarni Nice idea. I looked at some, but in those cases it appears the answer is in the comments to the question. I don't wan't to just copy the comments into an answer. Actually I will update my question to include this case too.

Comment: I've found plenty of questions that had several upvotes and no answer in the comments but maybe we're visiting different tags. There are lots of unanswered interesting questions around, but finding them can be a challenge.

Comment: If the answer is in the comments to an "unanswered" question, feel no shame in posting an answer expanding on those comment "answers." If the answer is literally just the comment, post it as a community wiki answer. If you expand on the comment, you may get a better reception by adding phrases like, "SomeUser stated in this comment that, ..." followed by an explanation. SomeUser didn't post an answer; it's their fault if they wanted the reputation from your answer

Answer (score 31):

The general etiquette is *don't*. If you truly have nothing substantive to add to the existing answers, move on to some other question.

> I like to answer questions on SO as a form of learning, to reinforce, challenge, and refine my current understanding, as well as helping the asker of the question.

If you want to solve the problem as a learning exercise, that's fine. But that doesn't mean you have to *post* the solution.

Answer (score 9):

Duplicate content in any form is not welcome, do not post knowingly duplicate answers whether to same or different questions.

If you *know* that your answer will not add anything new to existing ones, then it is "not useful" and open for downvotes as well as for potential "plagiarized content" flags... Similar answers posted within minutes of each other usually would get equal treatment, but trying to post essentially the same answer visibly later just looks as pure attempt to gain rep for nothing.

If you have new information that is strongly related to the question, you should consider if it can be made into complete answer (possibly with "as … answer shows you can {half sentence summary of answer}" link) or should be left as comment either on the question or an existing answer.

Editing new information into existing answer is desired behavior from the post author. If information clearly obtained from other posts attribution is needed. Note that frequently information is readily available in a product documentation/source and the same updates can be obtained independently. Same unwritten rule applies as for similar posts - if happen in shortly after posting own answer - consider chance of author doing they own research, if clearly posted way after other answers added the new info - expect attribution.

Comment: You might want to rewrite the last paragraph. I mostly understand the first part of it, but it gradually becomes unintelligible for me towards the end.

Comment: OP is asking about editing in information from one answer into another answer, not new information from documentation or other sources.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like the gamication of StackOverflow is taking a toll on you. You aren't by any means obligated to answer questions. It's fine and great if you can, but you **don't have to**.

If other people answer questions in a better way than you can, look at what they have to say and incorporate that knowledge. As one answer suggested, you can even try to solve the problems without giving an answer.

**Remember**: reputation is gamification and nothing more.

You don't *really* gain anything by farming lots of it. If you can answer a question comprehensively, do so. If you can't, don't. We don't expect anything from you, except that you are nice to people when you decide to comment or answer.

Comment: while it is true that rep is just a number that gains you nothing, but for some people, seeing it raising might be more satisfaction than eating something made by Ramsay.

Answer (score 3):

> What about if the answer is in a comment, not a proper answer?

My view is that comments are **not** answers.

And therefore you are allowed write an answer saying exactly the same as a comment even without making a reference to the comment.

Comment: It could make sense to make it a community wiki in that case.

Comment: @DidierL Agree that in some cases it could make sense. However, in most cases a "comment-answer" simply points to the failing line (e.g. change `i<=j` to `i<j`) while an answer will (or at least should) have some further explanation telling why that change is needed. In such cases I see no reason to make it  a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

On other stack exchange websites, you just mention that someone else answered in a comment and then repeat their answer while adding some of your own information to it.

For example:

"Like @PleaseDon'tLetThisBeARealUser said c++ is objectively less cool than python because the python community is funnier.

The language is named after Montey Python.... we use spam and egg instead of foo and bar....."

I would expect something of that form to be fine on Stack Overflow too.

I'd also expect it to be okay to simply restate information found entirely in other answers if you think you can explain it better than the other answerers have. If you can't, downvotes will probably correct you.

Comment: I'm iffy on such answers. Often, the original comment was posted as a comment, not an answer, because the question should be closed as off-topic rather than be formally answered.