# Reasoning behind declined VLQ Answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Why was the VLQ flag I raised on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872176/jquery-set-data-attr/55174795#55174795) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYZAG.png)) declined?

[image: Declined flag response]

The answer doesn't add anything substantial compared to the existing and accepted answers.

Related: [Answering questions that already have a good answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373383/answering-questions-that-already-have-a-good-answer)

Comment: I always write a comment linking to the duplicate answer (if it's an exact duplicate or only copied part of another answer). Additionally, you can downvote and high-rep users can vote to delete (once it's -1 or lower).

Comment: Well, the reason behind declined was "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer". Really? It works but several answers had covered them already; whereas the newest and flagged answer didn't add any info or more explanation where it could be adding anything new. Which make me think of this being VLQ.

Comment: People in the review queue probably don't see the duplicate answer, as such, they will mostly judge the answer on its merits and if they copied a good answer, they will vote 'looks ok'. Therefore, always leave a comment (if there isn't one already) indicating it's a duplicate.

Comment: Tbh, it's not they don't see they didn't bother. Personally I always go to link, and check why the flag was flagged. Well, if it's how the other people review stuffs I'll also comment next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody in the [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) (where your Very Low Quality flag would be handled) made a decision - the flag [was invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55174795/timeline) at `2019-03-15 04:05:01Z` so the review itself became [no longer reviewable](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22470761).

Note that [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55174795/revisions) by [Nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) happened at `2019-03-15 06:12:58Z` so it wasn't the edit that invalidated the review, and therefore your flag.

Note that an edit to a post with a VLQ flag will result in the flag being marked helpful (though this is [a contentious issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364985/1364007)).

---

Right, now that the *mechanics* of we your flag was rejected, let's look at the answer itself.

It's not clear *exactly why* your flag was invalidated - it could have been handled by a moderator (moderators see VLQ flags) who didn't see *why* you flagged it. See [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007), which says:

> If you're reviewing low quality posts, I'd like you to read this. All of it. Not skim it, not just vote up/down with everyone else. In exchange, I'll keep it short. Or if you are too busy, here you go:
>
> > TL;DR: Review carefully. Don't delete everything. Deletion is for things that actually aren't answers, not for low-quality answers or "wrong" answers. Flag incorrect comments from review as "not constructive".

If I had to say, I'd say you raised the wrong flag. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174795/1364007) by [ANCY MATHEW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9786059/ancy-mathew), in its entirety (and before the edit fixed the formatting), is:

> $("#you").attr("data-you","New Value");

which is strictly an answer, albeit not a good one.

If your objection was that it didn't add anything over the other answers, you *could* raise a custom flag on it, saying something like

> This answer is a duplicate of other answers on this question, like {this one} or {this one}. Please delete it.

But you raised a VLQ flag. If I came across the answer in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue (and it had no comments on it), I would have opted to edit it, not vote to delete it.

See [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380873/1364007) by [Yvette Colomb ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/yvette-colomb) to [Should I mod-flag duplicate answers for deletion, or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380811/1364007) which, as the title implies, asks about declined custom flags on duplicate answers:

> **The best way to address flags is to treat mods as literal thinkers.**
>
> *[I sure am](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379036/3956566).*
>
> - If an answer is an *exact* duplicate, feel free to state that.
> - If an answer is a rough copy of another answer and adds nothing else to the original answer, state that. Don't state it's a duplicate, our brains look for copied content, not what is essentially an identical answer.
> - If an answer is an abbreviated version of another answer and adds no more information, say that. I have an auto comment I use when deleting such answers:
>
>   > This answer doesn't add anymore information that is already provided in the previous answers. Try not to duplicate content. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for explaining, unlike those who DV and not doing anything else :) After it was declined I found another answer and I used a custom mod flag similar to your explanation let's hope it's not declined as well.

Comment: The result is settled. It's deemed as helpful.

Comment: Aha - I'm pleased that this was a good outcome for you.

Comment: _"I'd say you raised the wrong flag. [...] [The post] is strictly an answer"_ The OP did not raise a "Not An Answer" flag; the problem is in the way the VLQ/NAA flags are conflated in review.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Isn't the underlying issue that the answer was flagged and there was no additional context for the reviewer (either a normal user in the LQPRQ, or a moderator) to know that the answer doesn't add anything to the existing answers? If a comment was left on the answer, or a custom flag made, then there would have been a better chance of the flag being marked helpful. Would you, if you saw that answer in the review queue without the formatting, have looked to see if it was a duplicated answer, or would you have added the formatting?

Comment: The fact that VLQ and NAA are dealt with (by non-moderators) in the same queue is a problem, I agree.

Comment: Having explanation attached would have made it easier for someone to review, yes, but I would also expect a reviewer to take a moment to look around before taking action.